# Scroll doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

This is my code:

```
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 20);
   JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
   JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

And I'm adding the text area:

```
  add(textArea);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, *select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `JScrollPane` and not the `JTextArea` to your container:

```
add(s);
```